# wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem : Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

In production server (ubuntu 14.04) getting this error while PDF download

referred link and tried

https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/bd89079245923c04be6b0f92af431c10

$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x86: 1: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x86: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

any help?

Comment: I'm confused... The gem contains a pre-packaged binary. Surely you'd need to either install via `apt-get` **or** via `rubygems`; not both?

Comment: Do you have a strong need to install it via a gem? If not, I'd suggest uninstalling that, and just installing the library via apt-get (as per your above link).

Comment: @TomLord  removed installed via apt-get and tried didn't work. Again remove from gem, installed via apt-get and getting error

 can't find executable wkhtmltopdf for gem wkhtmltopdf-binary. wkhtmltopdf-binary is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)

Comment: "can't find executable wkhtmltopdf for gem wkhtmltopdf-binary." --- Why would you get this error if you've uninstalled the `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem? I'm guessing you removed it from the `Gemfile`, but didn't actually uninstall it.

Comment: Below error is due to removal from gem, installed via apt-get 

error can't find executable wkhtmltopdf for gem wkhtmltopdf-binary. wkhtmltopdf-binary is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception) –

Comment: Even if i check my version 

$wkhtmltopdf --version


/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x86: 1: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x86: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: which wkhtmltopdf

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: do I need to follow this https://gist.github.com/srmds/2507aa3bcdb464085413c650fe42e31d

Comment: Uninstall the gem. Your output above shows that it's still installed.

Comment: # sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

Comment: similar but 14.04 https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3535